# Can't print french accents with python and subprocess

Tags: python, python-3.x, subprocess

I'm trying to get the files and directories of the current working directory with

```
info = subprocess.run("dir", shell=True, capture_output=True)
print(info.stdout)
```

but I have files with `é` and they are printed as `,` instead...

I also have a problem with the free bytes, I get that :

```
49ÿ372ÿ921ÿ856 octets libres
```

I tried to decode it but I get an error saying `AttributeError: 'std_output' object has no attribute 'decode'`

So apparently it's already decoded.

Comment: What version of Python is this? Presumably you are using Windows here?

Comment: Yes on windows with python 3.8.3

Answer (score 0):

The accent aigu "é" is actually two characters when put in a UTF string. It's  "´ – e", so this *is* the expected behavior.

Also, you don't need `subprocess` for listing a directory. You could just do:

```py
import os
os.listdir(".")
```

Comment: thanks, but I need subprocess for other things in that program

Comment: so I'd like to fix the problem with the subprocess library, how could I do that ?

Comment: and with that command I don't get the same output as with `dir`, I don't have the size of the files etc

Comment: for your last question, here's how to get the size: `[(f, os.path.getsize(f)) for f in os.listdir(".")]` running a shell child process for something you can easily do in native python is generally considered to be a bad practice.

Comment: If you just have to run a shell command, I guess `subprocess.check_output` is what you're looking for.

Comment: thanks for the comand, however, I don't get any output, I have to print it and it's a list. Is that normal ?

Comment: Yes, `check_output` gives you the command's output in its return value and you can decide whether you wanna print it or parse it or whatever.